# Websphere Liberty session timeout

Tags: session, websphere

I am using websphere liberty. I need to set the session expiry for my web application to value t. What value should be set for LTPA expiry? Since LTPA expiry time start from login, where the session expiry time is counted from last activity

Answer (score 1):

LTPA timeout is fixed, so if you want LTPA expiration to happen less often you can set it to typical working hours of your users e.g. 8h.
You can set it in the `<ltpa>` entry in `server.xml`.

```
<ltpa keysFileName="yourLTPAKeysFileName.keys" keysPassword="keysPassword" expiration="480" />
```

If you just want to logout user when the session expires use the following config element:

```
<webAppSecurity  logoutOnHttpSessionExpire="true"/>
```

More details can be found here: [Customizing SSO configuration using LTPA cookies in Liberty](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEQTP_liberty/com.ibm.websphere.wlp.doc/ae/twlp_sec_sso.html)

Comment: Setting LTPA timeout to 8h irrespective of session timeout - even if session expires, a new session will be created and the user will never log out until 8 hours.

Comment: @HiteshBajaj  - What is your actual problem? LTPA is fixed, session timeout is inactivity , so you can have session lasting for all day if user will be constantly clicking. If you want to logout user when the session expires use the `logoutOnHttpSessionExpire=true` setting.

Comment: consider a scenario, where LTPA timeout is 6 hours and inactivity timeout is 2 hours.
Now the user signs in, LTPA is generated. The user continues to use the website for 6 hours. The session is not inactive at this stage, but the LTPA token expires and the user is redirected for fresh authentication. (The session is not destroyed, but fresh authentication is required). How to deal with this.

Comment: @HiteshBajaj - I've already written that - if you want to avoid expiration of LTPA set it to very long value (12h), so it doesnt expire for the whole user working day. It is not possible to by pass user reauthentication when LTPA expires, unless you are using BASIC auth (which unfortunately prevents logout) or some sso mech like SPNEGO (which performs reauth behind the scene).

Comment: thanks for your reply. I intend to logout session honoring the session inactivity time specified. I want to somehow bypass LTPA expiry(by refreshing the token before it expires). is there a way?

Comment: @HiteshBajaj , no there is no way to refresh LTPA token, other than I've already pointed.